# Apache Permissions Linux

Tags: linux, permissions

- wordpress runs as the `apache` user
- `apache` is in the `developers` group
- all folders are `775`
- all files are `664`
- all folders and files are in the `developers` group

Why does `apache` need to own the files in order for Wordpress to install/update plugins?

Answer (score 0):

At the outset, `root` starts the Apache server. Apache relinquishes the `root` privileges on startup and will have limited privileges of the `apache` user.

So, when you upload files, Apache can't write into WordPress plugins folder, the plugin installation fails. You can solve this problem in two ways.

1. Give write access to plugins folder to a group and make the `apache`
   user member of this group.
2. Or, make the folder owned by `apache` user

Watch out for `umask` setting. You need to set it wherever apache environment variables are setup.

```
"umask 002"
```

The `umask` will have an impact on permissions of new files and directories created while installing plugins.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does apache need to own the files in order for Wordpress to install/update plugins?

Because your permissions model sucks.

Deciding what permissions to put on what files is as important a part of deploying a website as writing code and configuring your webserver. Clearly the installation here has been designed in such a way to allow updates to the code to be applied via the web. There are 2 common solutions to the problem - making the files and directories writeable by everyone and making the files/directories owned by your webserver uid. Both are very bad for security.

It is inevitable when working with a lot of applications that you will need some designated areas that the webserver uid can write to - these should be outside the document root and all code execution banned within those directories.

With the permissions you have, Apache can read all the files/directories via any of user / group / other, and write as user or group. So there is some redundancy here, Apache does not NEED to ow the files to write to them - but this is not the problem. That Apache can write to any code (or config) files is a problem.

The right solution to the right problem needs some effort.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you're uploading and updating the files Apache are running under 'apache' user and it needs to have privileges to change files for that.

Most likely the easier way will be making apache the owner of the plugins directory only, not all web root directory for security reasons.

You can take a look [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/linux-access-privileges-2-access-again.html) for more recommendations about file permissions.